# Why does this MySQL query return 0 results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all records in the past 5 minutes but it is returning nothing..

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_actions`) WHERE `IP` = '127.0.0.1' AND `type` = 'Failed Login' AND date =DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: What does your data look like? We could assume it's returning nothing because there really is nothing...

Comment: It's a fairly easy to spot logic mistake in the query guys, you don't need any data to see it. The downvotes weren't necessary.

Comment: I think the downvote is harsh here. His error is clear given his explanation of what he's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

It's returning nothing because there no results for what you're asking for.... a date of **exactly** 5 minutes ago.

You should not use the `=` operator for your `DATE`, you should be using inequalities.

That is, you want the date greater than 5-minutes-ago

Answer (score 2):

It should be `date >` not `date =`, which would only match rows exactly equal to the time 5 minutes ago.

As an example, if it is currently 12:30PM, to find the rows that are within the last 5 minutes, you want all those with a time greater than 12:25PM. Querying only for rows with a time equal to 12:25PM won't give you those recorded at 12:26PM, 12:27PM, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM user_actions WHERE IP = '127.0.0.1' AND type = 'Failed Login' AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```